# chrome on iOS: How to disable microphone access popup when mic is turned on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microphone, chrome-ios

Whenever the mic is turned on on an iOS device using Chrome browser, a popup saying **"Microphone Access Allowed"** appears.

[image]

Chrome does not have any documentation/blog regarding the popup. All it has is [the support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1) that says:

> ...
> When prompted, tap Allow or Don't Allow.
> To immediately edit your preference, tap Edit.

I have a web app that turns microphone on/off frequently which results in the said popup appearing constantly ruining the UX. Is there any way to fix this? Say, for example, make it appear only once, better, disable it altogether?

I understand that Chrome is doing it to catch user's attention that an app is accessing the microphone. But in my case, the UX suffers greatly when the core of my app involves using microphone. Has anyone have had similar experience before?